# "NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)" error with the new (angular 6+) method of DI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Angular 8, Couldn't find any question here that helped me. following this tutorial: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/first-app, I've created a PhotoService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

class Photo {
  data: any;
}

export class PhotoService {

  public photos: Photo[] = [];

  constructor(private camera: Camera) { }

  takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // Add new photo to gallery
      this.photos.unshift({
          data: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData
      }); }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
      console.log("Camera issue: " + err);
  });

  }

}
```

And then injected it in the relevant component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PhotoService } from '../services/photo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab2Page {

  constructor(public photoService: PhotoService) {}

}
```

But this produced an error:

```
consolelogs.js:49 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Tab2Page -> PhotoService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Tab2Page -> PhotoService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for PhotoService!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Tab2Page -> PhotoService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Tab2Page -> PhotoService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for PhotoService!
```

But when I inject the service in the old way like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PhotoService } from '../services/photo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss'],
  providers: [PhotoService]
})
export class Tab2Page {

  constructor(public photoService: PhotoService) {}

}
```

Everything works fine..Why the new way of injection doesn't work?
thanks.

Comment: Why did you put Photo class between Injectable decorator and PhotoService?

Comment: Why do you have the `@Injectable` decorator above the `Photo` class? Try moving that just above the `PhotoService`.

Comment: They didn't mention in the tutorial that the location would make any difference XD, thanks.

Comment: Why is the old way of injecting works even if the Photo class is right under the @Injectable decorator?